# Rewriting a function to accept AsRef<Path> instead of &Path

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker

How do I write the following function to accept not only `Path`, but also `String` or `&str`?

```rust
fn find_database1<'a>(path: &'a Path) -> Option<&'a Path> {
    path.parent()
}
```

After writing the above mentioned function, I wanted to convert it into a form to not just accept a `Path`, but also `String` or `&str`. I ended up with the two following versions, each of which does not work. Function `find_database3` was an attempt to get a better understanding of the cause, but unfortunately I don't see why it's not working.

```rust
fn find_database2<'a, P>(path: P) -> Option<&'a Path>
where
    P: 'a + AsRef<Path>,
{
    path.as_ref().parent()
}

fn find_database3<'a, P>(path: P) -> Option<&'a Path>
where
    P: 'a + AsRef<Path>,
{
    let _path: &'a Path = path.as_ref();
    _path.parent()
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `path`
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     path.as_ref().parent()
   |     ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |     `path` is borrowed here

error[E0597]: `path` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:27
   |
14 | fn find_database3<'a, P>(path: P) -> Option<&'a Path>
   |                   -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
18 |     let _path: &'a Path = path.as_ref();
   |                --------   ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                |
   |                type annotation requires that `path` is borrowed for `'a`
19 |     _path.parent()
20 | }
   | - `path` dropped here while still borrowed
```

```rust
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path_str: &str = "root/path";
    let path_string: String = path_str.to_string();
    let path_path: &Path = &Path::new(path_str);

    let root = find_database1(path_path);
    println!("{:?}", root);

    find_database2(path_str);
    find_database2(path_string);
    let root = find_database2(path_path);
    println!("{:?}", root);
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e18906113396d351410b59faa3727f5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Path::parent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.parent) has this signature:

```
fn parent(&self) -> Option<&Path>;
```

So the returned result holds a reference to some data owned by the caller. You can't call `parent()` on a `String` and then drop the `String` because that invalidates the reference returned by `parent()`. You can make your function work if you loosen the requirement from taking `String`s and accept `&String`s instead. Example:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

// takes &str, &String, or &Path
fn find_database2<'a, P>(path: &'a P) -> Option<&'a Path>
    where P: 'a + ?Sized + AsRef<Path>,
{
    path.as_ref().parent()
}

fn main() {
    let path_str: &str = "root/path";
    let path_string: String = path_str.to_string();
    let path_path: &Path = &Path::new(path_str);

    find_database2(path_str); // &str
    find_database2(&path_string); // &String
    let root = find_database2(path_path); // &Path
    println!("{:?}", root);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee8417a0eb1673195aef605da18fd651)

On the other hand if you really want to accept `String`s you can convert the `Option<&Path>` to a `Option<PathBuf>` inside the function body. This works because `PathBuf` is the owned version of `Path`:

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

// takes &str, &String, String, &Path, or PathBuf
fn find_database2<'a, P>(path: P) -> Option<PathBuf>
    where P: 'a + AsRef<Path>,
{
    path.as_ref().parent().map(|path| {
        let mut path_buf = PathBuf::new();
        path_buf.push(path);
        path_buf
    })
}

fn main() {
    let path_str: &str = "root/path";
    let path_string: String = path_str.to_string();
    let path_path: &Path = &Path::new(path_str);

    find_database2(path_str); // &str
    find_database2(&path_string); // &String
    find_database2(path_string); // String
    let root = find_database2(path_path); // &Path
    println!("{:?}", root);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e994be46ccbea4f93d91f5e59fdb1b9)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! After giving it another thought, your first version (accepting an &String instead of String) is the one I actually wanted. Your example also helped me to understand the ?Sized marker better.

Comment: In both examples, the `'a` lifetime spec is optional.